# Bash: echo result of multiple commands with ';'

Tags: bash

I've got two commands, which echo me following result:

```
[root@in SNMP]# /usr/protei/utils/SNMP/check_cpe.sh general;/usr/protei/utils/SNMP/check_cpe.sh smpp;
OK
VERY OK
```

Next, i'm gonna form this command line through cycle and the question is, how Can i echo result of these commands to console?

```
#!/bin/sh

RUN="/usr/protei/utils/SNMP/check_cpe.sh general;/usr/protei/utils/SNMP/check_cpe.sh smpp;"
RES=`$RUN`
echo "$RES"
```

Gives me nothing. If i'm adding >>/dev/null  at the end of each command, i recieve only first result 'OK'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to group the execution of two commands, write a function.

```
run() {
  /usr/protei/utils/SNMP/check_cpe.sh general
  /usr/protei/utils/SNMP/check_cpe.sh smpp
}
```

You have two file descriptors in a Unix shell: standard output and standard error. If you see an "OK" although you have redirected standard output to /dev/null, the application writes the "OK" to standard error. If you want to combine standard error and standard output, do this:

```
result=$(run 2>&1)
```

Do not use back quotes in 2018.